# Assuming that $H \cap K = \{1_G\}$ and $G = \langle H, K \rangle$, prove that $G \cong H \times K$, why do we need both $H, K\mathrel{\unlhd}G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, direct-product

The question is the same as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363036/g-a-group-and-h-k-mathrel-unlhdg-assuming-that-h-cap-k-1-g-and), and I understand the proof in it.

But I don't know why do we need both $H, K\mathrel{\unlhd}G$?
I think just one of them being a normal subgroup will be enough.

W.L.O.G let $H\mathrel{\unlhd}G$ Then $hk=(khk^{-1})k=kh$, and the rest are the same as the post.

Where did I go wrong?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Your equation $hk = (khk^{-1})k$ is wrong. The dihedral group of order $6$ with $|H|=3$ and $|K|=2$ is a counterexample to your claim. In the situation you describe, you get a *semidirect product* $H \rtimes K$ rather than a direct product.

Comment: Oh, I got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality $hk = khk^{-1}k$ seems wrong, unless $k$ and $h$ commute - but this is exactly what needs to be shown.

You need both $H$ and $K$ to be normal in $G$ because in a direct product every element of $H$ commutes with every element of $K$. You can show that this is equivalent to asking that both $H$ and $K$ are normal in $G$. If you only ask that $H$ is normal, you get what is called a semidirect product of $H$ and $K$, denoted $H \rtimes K$. To see this in action. Consider the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ of order six. You can show that $\mathbb{Z}_{6} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. On the other hand, the symmetric group on three letters is $S_{3} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{3} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_{2}$, and you can check here that $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ is not normal in $S_3$.

Here are Wikipedia links to this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product

Comment: I got it, thank you!